# Determine what class is a closer ancestor of an element

Tags: jquery

How can I determine what class is a closer ancestor of an element in jquery?

I can easily do

```
$("#elementID").closest(".class1")
```

and

```
$("#elementID").closest(".class2")
```

but this doesn't tell me which one was found first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, you can use any selector in `.closest(...)` and jQuery will stop as soon as it matches that selector, so...

```
$("#elementID").closest(".class1, .class2")
```

...is what you want.

Comment: took me way too long to realize, but I was doing .closest(".class1", ".class2"), which is two parameters instead of the one

Answer (score 1):

Multiple selectors are supported by JQ. Just separate the selectors by a comma.

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div id="elementID">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  alert($("#elementID").closest(".class1, .class2")[0].className)
</script>
```